# Thread : Let consumer thread read data only when there is change in data

Tags: multithreading

I am working on a multi-threaded based Web application developed using Java EE.

I have two threads inside that application similar to a producer and consumer, where one thread continuously reads the data from a third party API (Socket connection), and updates it to a cache. The other thread (consumer) continuously tries to read from the cache.

My question is if there is any way that I can improve the performance of the consumer thread (I mean it only reads the data from the cache) when and only there is a change in data.

Comment: #1: Define *change* in data. i.e. what happens to the 'cache' each time there is a *change*? Are there new records of data added to the 'cache' that need to be processed?; #2: Why is it a 'cache'? Sounds to me like you should be using a queue.; #3: What does your current implementation look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) (choose an implementation like `ArrayBlockingQueue` for example). It will block (suspend) the consumer calling `take` until there is data available in the buffer.

Comment: Even though if i use an BlockingQueue , how does it stop my Thread doing a Continuous poll as all this happening inside a while(true) condition of that Thread . Please advice .

Comment: @Preethi Jain: If you call `take` on the blocking queue and there are no items the calling thread will be blocked automatically until something appears in the queue. There is no need for polling.

Comment: Thanks Tudor  , so can i manage with using  blocking  Queue ,and  no need to use wait and notify methods in Threads ??

Comment: @Preethi Jain: Exactly, blocking queue already has a mechanism like this implemented internally.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of way to do.

Producer-consumer queue (aka BlockingQueue in Java, as suggested by Tudor) is one way.

You may also make use of wait()/notify() so the consumer wait for a object, and producer notify the consumer when there is update.  Start from Java5, you can even make use of Condition for such purpose.